# Getting minimum element from maximum priority queue

Tags: priority-queue

What is the most efficient way to get the minimum element from a maximum `priority queue`?

Let's say i have created a generic `priority queue`. Now this `queue` contains cats and cats has a variable fish, which is the number of fishes the cat has eaten and i want to get the cat that has eaten the fewest fish and give her some more fish, then `sort` the `priority queue` again(which means i call `swim()` to get the fish that has eaten closer to the root). But since the `priority queue` is a max one( it has to be max , it can't be min) how can i get the cat that has eaten the fewest fishes?

Comment: To make this a suitable StackOverflow question you probably need to better describe your use-case (TBH, right now it sounds like you're asking StackOverflow to do a homework problem for you), and show example of what you've researched, what you've tried, and where it's not working and/or where it's confusing.

Comment: @RookieRick You are correct, i've been struggling with this question for 2 days now, so i'll organize it a little bit better and come ask again. Also, thanks for the tips, although i've been consulting stack overflow for years now, it's my first time asking a question. Thanks for taking the time to comment!

Comment: There is some discussion of how to ask/answer "homework" type questions at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions that may be helpful in garnering good responses (as far as I know there's no official stance/policy but some strong opinions on either side of the issue).  Good luck!!

Comment: What's the underlying implementation of your priority queue?  The solutions would be wildly different if the implementation is a binary search tree vs a binary heap vs an ordered list, for instance.  Also, you can often trade storage for speed.  Are you allowed to use any auxiliary data structures?

Comment: @pjs: That's true only if he has access to the underlying representation. If the implementation is opaque and all he has is the standard `insert`, `peek`, and `remove`, then the underlying representation is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Given a priority queue in which the top element is the largest, the only way to get the smallest item is to remove all of the elements from the queue. The last one you remove is the smallest item. The complexity of that approach is O(n log n). Plus you'll have to save the items you've popped and put them back into the queue after you've removed the last one.

It appears that you've implemented the priority queue as a binary max heap. If that's the case, then the smallest item will be a leaf, which by definition will be in the last n/2 items. So, if you have access to the backing array, you could search the last n/2 items for the smallest item. That's an O(n) operation.

If removing the smallest item is something you need to do on a regular basis, you might consider implementing a [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap).

Answer (score 0):

Redefine the ordering property for fish.

If you're working in a language which uses the `comparator` concept, one way to do this is to write a comparator that reverses the default ordering property for fish.  Another alternative is to store the negative of the fish count when creating/pushing a cat.  The logic could be built into cat objects, so the user only sees and manipulates positive quantities of fish, but they are internally stored as negative values.